# WSDL declaration using nuSoap php

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, nusoap

I am using nuSoap to create a webservice.  I am having trouble doing the wsdl declaration (I have no idea how it should be done).  Here is what I have so far:

```
// -----  Ingredients--------------------------------------------------------------------
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Ingredients'
'complexType',
'struct',
'sequence',
'',
array(
    'Ingredient' => array('name'=>'Ingredient','type'=>'xsd:string'),
)
);
// ----- Steps -------------------------------------------------------------------------
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Steps'
'complexType',
'struct',
'sequence',
'',
array(
    'Step' => array('name'=>'Step','type'=>'xsd:string'),
)
);
// ---- Cocktails ----------------------------------------------------------------

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Cocktail',
'complexType',
'struct',
'sequence',
'',
array(
    'Name' => array('name'=>'Name','type'=>'xsd:string'),
    //here i am suppose to add element Ingredients and steps
    'Picture' => array('name'=>'Picture','type'=>'xsd:string'),
    'Background' => array('name'=>'Background','type'=>'xsd:string'), 
)
);
// ---- Cocktails[] --------------------------------------------------------------

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'Cocktails',
'complexType',
'array',
'',
'SOAP-ENC:Array',
array(),
array(
    array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:Cocktail[]')
),
'tns:Cocktail'
);
```

I don't know how to add `Ingredients` and `Steps` which are supposed to be complex type containing a series of ingredients and steps. The XML that it is suppose to represent is as follows:

```
<Cocktails>
<Cocktail  Type = "Alcoholic">
    <Name>Cosmopolitan</Name>
    <Ingredients>
        <Ingredient>4-6 cracked ice cubes</Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>2 measure vodka</Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>1 measure Triple Sec</Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>1 measure lime juice</Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>1 measure cranberry juice</Ingredient>
        <Ingredient>orange peel strip to decorate</Ingredient>
    </Ingredients>
    <Steps>
        <Step>Put the cracked ice cubes in cocktail shaker.</Step>
        <Step>Pour the liquid ingredient over the ice cubes.</Step>
        <Step>Shaked vigourously until well frosted.</Step>
        <Step>Strain into a chilled cocktail glass and decorate with the orange peel.</Step>
    </Steps>
    <Picture>Cosmopolitan.jpg</Picture>
    <Background>CosmopolitanHD.jpg</Background>
</Cocktail>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.